# Timer Countdown Time Format

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I have built a countdown timer in WPF following the tutorial here: [Simple COUNTDOWN With C# - WPF](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_F_v_ISeDk)

Here is the code snippet I'm using:

```
void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (time > 0)
       {
         if (time <= 60)
         {
           RebootCountdownWindowTimerText.Foreground = Brushes.Red;          
           time--;
           RebootCountdownWindowTimerText.Text
                               = string.Format("00:0{0}:{1}", time / 60, time % 60);
        }
         time--;
         RebootCountdownWindowTimerText.Text 
                               = string.Format("00:0{0}:{1}", time / 60, time % 60);
        }
        else
        {
           Timer.Stop();
           serviceController.RebootComputer();
        }
    }
```

Problem is, when the timer counts down into lower seconds, the format changes. For example, counting down from 1 minute and 12 seconds:

```
00:01:12
00:01:11
00:01:10
00:01:9
00:01:8
etc...
```

How can I re-factor the code so that it properly shows a 0 in the "tens" place when counting down?

Comment: Apart from the answer, don't rely on a timer to be called -exactly- every 1 second. In other words, don't do `time--`, calculate the difference with the last time. Also, you are substracting TWO units whenever the timer is under 60... so if the timer interval is 1 second, your last minute will happen in 30 seconds :-)

Answer (score 4):

Use the Number format `D#`, where `#` determines the number of digits so for example

```
var time =112;
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("00:{0:D2}:{1:D2}", time / 60, time % 60));
```

will give

```
00:01:52
```

Comment: Slightly neater (in my opinion) would be `Console.WriteLine(string.Format("00:{0:D2}:{1:D2}", (time / 60), (time % 60)));` - that is putting the format specifier in the format string and not using `ToString`.

Comment: Perfect! I wasn't aware of that string format convention. Very elegant solution.